# Multiple Ajax Requests (with one callback)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm sending multiple ajax requests and want to get a callback if all the requests are successful. I've found `$.when($.ajax(), [...]).then(function(results){},[...]);` but that only works when you know in advance how many you're going to do. In my case, it varies depending on user input.

I tried the following but I'm not sure where or how `$.when` fits in:

```
$.when(
    $('#piecesTable tr').not(':first').each(function(){

        // ...some prep...

        $.ajax({
            // ...args here...
        });
    })
).then(function() {
    // All requests are done
});
```

How do I use the results of all those separate `$.ajax` calls with `$.when`? Or do I handle this some other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the general structure of what you're looking for is something like this:

```
var requests = [];

// Populate requests array with ajax requests.
requests.push($.ajax({
    // ...
}));

// Add as many requests as you want to the array.

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    var args = $.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    // args should contain the results of your ajax requests.

    // Do whatever with the results.
});
```

Comment: just a question when puting the ajax inside the push its giving me a error this.pushStack is not a function.

Comment: @H.C: It's `push`, not `pushStack`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a modern alternative to the `$.when.apply($, arrayOfPromises)` beast: `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function(arrayOfResults) {
    // Use arrayOfResults
});
```

`Promise.all` expects an array of *thenables* and returns a promise that resolves with an array of the results when all of the thenables have resolved. It's fine with jQuery's promises, because all it requires is that they be [*thenables*](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-7), which they are.

You can use this on any browser with `Promise` support, or if you include a `Promise` shim/polyfill.

So in your case, you'd build the array:

```
var arrayOfPromises = [];
$('#piecesTable tr').not(':first').each(function(){

    // ...some prep...

    arrayOfPromises.push($.ajax({       // ** Push this promise into the array
        // ...args here...
    }));
});
```

*(Or you can build it with `$.map` or `Array#map`.)*

And then use the array:

```
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function(arrayOfResults) {
    // Use arrayOfResults
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation :

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

Execute the function `myFunc` when both ajax requests are successful, or `myFailure` if either one has an error.

So you can use this system to send variable number of requests and still have the same callback functions :)

Adapted with @TW80000 answer :

```
var requests = [];
 ....
$.when.apply($, requests ).done( myFunc, myFailure );
```