# Sum of values from one or more arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the sum up of multiple Ajax calls,

I have written ajax method inside for loop as I need get multiple results,

```
  for (i = 0; i < invoice_ids.length; i++) {
      $.ajax({
            url: "payments/getInvoiceAmount",
            method: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"amount_tds": amount_tds, "invoice_id":invoice_ids[i]},
            success: function(response) {
               //need get the sum of response

            }
        });
    }
```

the above ajax method gives multiple results, results will be like

```
 [{"invoice_amount":"1000"}]
 [{"invoice_amount":"1000"}]
 [{"invoice_amount":"1000"}]
 [{"invoice_amount":"1000"}]
 [{"invoice_amount":"1000"}]
```

How can I get output like **invoice_amount:5000**

Comment: The objects have the property `invoice_amount`. Your code tries to use the property `invoice_item_subtotal`...?

Comment: `response[i][0].invoice_amount`?

Comment: The sum variable is being assigned within the success function. You should try bringing the scope of Sum down one level so it can retain the total between ajax calls.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake, I have edited that

Comment: So your real problem is: "How to sum up the results from multiple Ajax calls?"

Comment: @JonasW. yes sir

Comment: Believe me, your arrays totally invalid!

Comment: My question is just sum up the results from multiple Ajax calls,

Comment: You can use jQuery `when`, or ES6 `promise.all()` syntax. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791115/multiple-ajax-requests-with-one-callback/38791279?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following

```
// Create an array of promises
var promises = [];
for (i = 0; i < invoice_ids.length; i++) {
     promises.push(performAction(amount_tds, invoice_ids[i]));
}

// Iterate over the responses and calcuate the sum 
Promise.all(promises).then((responses) => {
    var sum = responses.reduce((a,c) => a + c.reduce((acc, b) => acc + parseFloat(b.invoice_amount), 0), 0);
});

// Create a function that sends ajax
function performAction(amount_tds, invoice_id) {
      return $.ajax({
            url: "payments/getInvoiceAmount",
            method: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"amount_tds": amount_tds, "invoice_id":invoice_ids}
        });
}
```